# How can I maximize performance on EC2 with Django/Apache/mod_wsgi/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, django, apache, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running Django-powered site on EC2 m1.medium instance (3.75 Gb memory, 2 EC2 Compute Unit, 410 Gb instance storage, moderate performance) with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. MySQL settings on my EC2 instance are the following (from /etc/mysql/my.cnf):

> key_buffer              = 16M
>   max_allowed_packet      = 16M
>   thread_stack            = 192K
>   thread_cache_size       = 8
>   query_cache_limit       = 1M
>   query_cache_size        = 16M

The mod_wsgi settings from /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com:

> WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com user=me group=me processes=7
>   threads=20 maximum-requests=1000000

Given my configuration, what is the maximum number of processes/threads/requests I can set? I tried some values, but they led to MySQL crashing. Is it ok to set MySQL key_buffer to 0.75Gb (20% of the 3.75Gb RAM on the EC2 instance)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your MySQL variables seems very low. First of all the most important thing: what storage engine are you using? Key_buffer_size has only effect on **MyISAM** storage engine.

If you're using **MyISAM** do the followings:

```
> select sum(index_length) / 1024 / 1024 as index_size_MB from information_schema.Tables where Table_schema = 'knagy' and Engine = 'MyISAM';
+---------------+
| index_size_MB |
+---------------+
|    0.16992188 |
+---------------+
```

This will show you how big your indexes are. You should set roughly this value as **key_buffer_size** if you have enough RAM. But don't increase this higher than 50-60% of your free RAM.

If you're using **InnoDB** try to set the **innodb_buffer_pool** to the size of your dataset with indexes:

```
> select sum(index_length + data_length) / 1024 / 1024 as innodb_MB from information_schema.Tables where Table_schema = 'knagy' and Engine = 'InnoDB';
+--------------+
| innodb_MB    |
+--------------+
| 403.04687500 |
+--------------+
```

You can set it up to 80% of your free RAM of course consider that other application's memory usage.

Only with one of these changes you will get significant performance boost.

You can increase the **thread_cache_size** as well around 30-50 or more if you see **threads_created** status variable increasing fast.

Of course there are a lot of further optimizations but this will get you around the 80-90% of the possible maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any live monitoring at all of your site so you know what it is really doing? Watch my PyCon talk and one thing you will hopefully realise is that it all depends on your specific application and we know nothing about that.

http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/